# Silverlight 4, RIA Services & Data Annotations. Tooltips not appearing on DataForm

Tags: silverlight-4.0, data-annotations, wcf-ria-services, dataform

I'm having a problem with data annotations and the automatic tool tips on my DataForm fields.  The objects bound to the DataForm have been decorated with the Display and Description attributes e.g.

**[Display(Name = "Email Address:", Description="We do not sell your information!")]**
public string EmailAddress { get; set; }

The expected tooltips are not appearing on the DataForm next to the relevant fields.  In the example given I would expect to see an info icon next to the EmailAddress field with a pop up tooltip set to the Description value ("We do not sell your information!").

Has anyone else had a similar problem?  I am using Silverlight 4 and RIA Services.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have "System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations" in your References.
Also the DataForm must be editable (and in edit mode) for the ToolTips to show.